# Date object and time integer to datetime

Tags: pandas, date, datetime, time

All, I have a dataframe with a date column and an hour column. I am trying to combine those into a single timestamp. I tried many solutions available using datetime.datetime.combine and just implicitly extracting month day and year and creating a datetime stamp with it but all lead to some error.

```
    idOnController  date        eventTime           Energy  hour
0   5014            2018-05-31  2018-05-31 01:00:00 26.619  0
2   5014            2018-06-02  2018-06-02 02:00:00 29.251  0
3   5014            2018-06-03  2018-06-03 03:00:00 30.635  0
```

The datatypes are as follows

```
idOnController             int64
date                      object
eventTime         datetime64[ns]
Energy                   float64
hour                       int64
dtype: object
```

I am looking to combine date and hour into a timestamp that looks like eventTime and then replace eventTime with that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + df['hour'] * pd.to_timedelta('1H')
```

Output of `df.dtypes`:

```
idOnController             int64
date                      object
eventTime         datetime64[ns]
Energy                   float64
hour                       int64
new_date          datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

If you want to have the string timestamps you can do

```
df['new_date'] = df['new_date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: I tried that but the new_date doesn't show a time stamp. Only shows the date. I am expecting to see 2018-05-31 00:00:00 but only see 2018-05-31

Comment: They are timestamps, you can print `df.dtypes` to verify. Since the hours are `0`, they got printed out as exactly the date. If you want the *string timestamp*, you can use `dt.strftime`.

Comment: Got it. Can you help me by modifying your answer to show the timestamp as well. I am a python newbie , sorry. I would like the new_date to look like eventTime

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this would be (a bit more verbose though!):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year'] = df.date.dt.year
df['month'] = df.date.dt.month
df['day'] = df.date.dt.day

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month','day','hour']])
```